# What would be the simplest/most effective way to make a shinyApp using shinymanager package multilingual (depending on the user)?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a large shiny application used by multiple users and I use the shinymanager package to manage the credentials. Some users requested to have the user interface translated based on their own language.The desired languages (depending on the user) are: English, French and Dutch.

Only the UI components need a translation. I was wondering whether there would be a way to store language preferences in the sqlite credential database of the shinyapp package and then have all the UI translated based on that value, see a minimal example below to illustrate. The shinyadmin should be able to create a new user via the admin page and select language...

```
  credentials <- data.frame(
    user = c("shiny", "shinymanager"),
    password = c("azerty", "12345"),
    language = c("en","fr") # example.
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

Based on this how could I translate my UI components effectively ? (preferably keep the translation files in a distinct script/Json file or whatever.

Note that here I am not concerned about the shinymanager login page (where the user is not logged yet, therefore his language preference cannot be specified via the sqlite database).

[EDIT]

```
# server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  #### Credential login ####
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials =  check_credentials(sqlite_path, passphrase = "password")
  )
  output$lang <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)$language # see the credential file above
  })
```

Basically I want the UI below to change "This is a tab panel" to "Ceci est un onglet" if output$lang is == "fr". The difficulty I have here is with respect to the reactivity and server evaluation process. I would ideally avoid to have server-evaluated UI (i.e. with uiOutput & renderUi), as this increases the complexity of the code and the language does not change once the UI is initiated after login.

```
userinterface <- navbarPage('Dashboard', id="page", collapsible=TRUE, inverse=FALSE,
  tabPanel("This is a tab panel", module.ui("mymoduleui")) #some ui in module.ui
)

ui <- secure_app(userinterface,
                 enable_admin = TRUE)
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://appsilon.com/internationalization-of-shiny-apps-i18n/

Comment: Actually with dev version, you can choose language through login page, but we don't have dutch translation, but you can make a PR to add the labels based on this ones : https://github.com/datastorm-open/shinymanager/blob/master/R/language.R

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i18n could be used indeed but here my initial problem is more on the reactivity with shinymanager and have language  dependent on the user. i18n can be used once this is solved indeed and I probably will use that.